# katura video loading correctely but turning and not playing

Tags: javascript, ios, kaltura

i am developping a webapp which consist of playing video from katura , platfform, after i am going to load the link on ios webview

```
<html>
    <body>


        <div id="myEmbedTarget" style="width:400px;height:330px;"></div>
        <!-- Substitute {partnerId} for your Kaltura partner id, {uiConfId} for an actual player id, also known as the uiconf id and {entryId} for an actual entry id. -->
        <script src="http://vod.adicis.cd/p/102/sp/10200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/23448125/partner_id/102"></script>
        <script>
            kWidget.embed({
                          'targetId': 'myEmbedTarget',
                          'wid': '_102',
                          'uiconf_id' : '23448125',
                          'entry_id' : '0_rgexe9cj',
                          'flashvars':{ // flashvars allows you to set runtime uiVar configuration overrides.
                          'autoPlay': false,
                          'LeadWithHLSOnFlash': true,
                          'Kaltura.LeadHLSOnAndroid': true
                          },
                          'params':{ // params allows you to set flash embed params such as wmode, allowFullScreen etc
                          'wmode': 'transparent'
                          }
                          });
            </script>




        <script src="https://www.kaltura.com/p/1724401/sp/172440100/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/24758201/partner_id/1724401"></script>
        <div id="kaltura_player_1403472745">
            <script>
                kWidget.embed({
                              "targetId": "kaltura_player_1403472745",
                              "wid": "_1724401",
                              "uiconf_id": 24758201,
                              "flashvars": {},
                              "entry_id": "1_41psxz9r"
                              });
                </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

the video load well but when i click on play it is turning but not playing i try with pc browsers but not playing it is only play on android webview

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading a http video from a https site? Have you tried to inspect the page and see which network connections it requests? And which one fails?

Comment: it a http site, this is the domain http://vod.adicis.cd and what i dont understand how it is just working when load it in android webview but for others browsers it is load well and you see the thumnail you click but it is loading without the end